# Split a list in sublists according to charcter length

Tags: python

I have a list of strings and I like to split that list in different "sublists" based on the character length of the words in th list e.g:

```
List = [a, bb, aa, ccc, dddd]

Sublist1 = [a]
Sublist2= [bb, aa]
Sublist3= [ccc]
Sublist2= [dddd]
```

How can i achieve this in python ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

by using `itertools.groupby`:

```
 values = ['a', 'bb', 'aa', 'ccc', 'dddd', 'eee']
 from itertools import groupby
 output = [list(group) for key,group in groupby(sorted(values, key=len), key=len)]
```

The result is:

```
[['a'], ['bb', 'aa'], ['ccc', 'eee'], ['dddd']]
```

If your list is already sorted by string length and you just need to do grouping, then you can simplify the code to:

```
 output = [list(group) for key,group in groupby(values, key=len)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use dictionaries

```
>>> dict_sublist = {}
>>> for el in List:
...     dict_sublist.setdefault(len(el), []).append(el)
... 
>>> dict_sublist
{1: ['a'], 2: ['bb', 'aa'], 3: ['ccc'], 4: ['dddd']}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> l = ["a", "bb", "aa", "ccc", "dddd"]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for elem in l:
...     d[len(elem)].append(elem)
...
>>> sublists = list(d.values())
>>> print(sublists)
[['a'], ['bb', 'aa'], ['ccc'], ['dddd']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're happy with a list of lists, indexed by length, how about something like

```
by_length = []
for word in List:
   wl = len(word)
   while len(by_length) < wl:
      by_length.append([])
   by_length[wl].append(word)

print "The words of length 3 are %s" % by_length[3]
```